# Pass dynamic data attribute to content block in Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a dynamic template for `button`s in Blaze, looks like this (simplified):

**button.html**

```
<template name="Button">
  <button {{attributes}}>
    <span class="button__text">{{> UI.contentBlock}}</span>
  </button>
</template>
```

**button.js**

```
import {Template} from 'meteor/templating';
import cx from 'classnames';

import './button.html';

Template.Button.helpers({
  attributes() {
    const instance = Template.instance();
    let {data} = instance;

    return {
      disabled: data.disabled,
      'class': cx('button', data.class)
    };
  }
});
```

Attempt to set dynamic data attribute:

```
{{#Button class="js-add-contact" data-phase-index={{index}}}}Add Contact{{/Button}}
```

This insertion of `index` (let's assume it's just a simple, dynamic string) into `data-phase-index` throws an error: the content block was not expecting the `{{`. I am unsure of another way to get that dynamic data into the template. There's also the issue of getting the `data-` attributes recognized by Button in the `attributes()` helper. Can anyone clear this up?

Comment: Could you put the value of `index` into a helper and reference it in the attr `data-phase-index=getIndex`? This has worked for me in `Template.dynamic`s.

Comment: @CodeMonkey thanks for the input, index actually is a helper and I was just making a dumb mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply `data-phase-index=index` should work.

Since you are already within double curly braces for your `Button` template call, Meteor knows it will get interpreted values. For example, see that you have to use quotes around your string in `class="js-add-contact"`.

As usual, Meteor will try to interpret `index` from a helper, or from data context.

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple! Definitely solved the error being thrown. However, the second part of my question is still plaguing me - when trying to access the data attributes, they come back `undefined` even when using your method. If I console.log `event.target.dataset` when clicking the button, it prints `DOMStringMap {}`

Comment: Ahh never mind, it was `button__text` throwing the event, which doesn't have any of the attributes on it. Appreciate the help!

Comment: yw :-) Thank you for the feedback. I am glad you solved the 2nd part of your question.